# Does bestow curse's third option prevent you from using bonus action and reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, curses

*Bestow curse's* third option prevents the target from using its action:

> While cursed, the target must make a Wisdom saving throw at the start of each of its turns. If it fails, it wastes its action that turn doing nothing.

I'm aware that [preventing a creature from taking actions also prevents reactions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154624/does-preventing-a-creature-from-taking-actions-also-prevent-reactions), but the description says 'it wastes its action that turn doing nothing.' It wastes your action, but not bonus action or reaction, right? It also does not say 'it wastes its turn'.

**Can I still use bonus action and reaction when under this effect of *bestow curse*?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, you can still take bonus actions and reactions

*PHB*, p. 189:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed
> and **take one action**.

This *one action* is what *remove curse* refers to when it says that the target "wastes its action".

This is also supported by a Sage Advice Compendium entry (about *stinking cloud*) that uses the same wording of "wastes its action":

> **The stinking cloud spell says that a creature wastes
> its action on a failed save. So can it still use a move or
> a bonus action or a reaction?** Correct. The gas doesn’t
> immobilize a creature or prevent it from acting altogether,
> but the effect of the spell does limit what it can accomplish while the cloud lingers.